# find new line in textarea and put into array

Tags: php, input, textarea

I need to find a way to to break up the input of a textarea into a array with every enter the user pushes.
I have tried :

```
$a = explode('/n', $_POST['textarea_Input']);
$a = explode('\n', $_POST['textarea_Input']);
$a = explode('&#10', $_POST['textarea_Input']);
```

none worked.

every new line must go into its own array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$a = explode("\r", $_POST['textarea_Input']);
```

Comment: it works, I had singel quotes, I saw that u used dubbel. thank you.